# Windows Explorer control for WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, explorer

Is there a way to have a Windows Explorer on WPF? The closes I can get is the Web Browser, but it's not really what I need.

Please assist.

Thanks

Answer (score 21):

Check these out -

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPF_Explorer_Tree.aspx

and

http://gargmanoj.wordpress.com/2009/03/27/wpf-101-a-simple-windows-explorer-like-directory-browser/

Comment: Oops, this was asked a year ago! is it still okay if I answer this?

Comment: I like your second link, what a nice example.

Comment: @DheerajKumar Sure. As always, people should answer if they thing their answer has value according the asked question. This point also fits to old questions. If you think it has value, even against other answers, the go for it. Personally, I prefer your answer against the others. So thanks for this. Upvoted.

Answer (score 5):

JAM Software recently released a [WPF edition of their ShellBrowser controls](https://www.jam-software.com/shellbrowser_wpf/). They contain a wrapped Windows Explorer as well as custom built tree and list controls. Also included is a preview control similar to the one in the Windows Explorer on the right. Full disclosure: I am one of the developers of ShellBrowser.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the explorer browser control in the [Windows API Code Pack.](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack)  Compatible with Vista and 7, I believe.

Comment: I was about to suggest that, but it is a WinForms control, not WPF... however it could be used with a WindowsFormsHost

Comment: It is fine, I can still use that on WPF...but does Windows XP support that if I code it this way?

Comment: Dunno.  You'll have to test it.

Answer (score 1):

I have written a WinForms library that might help. It's not WPF but you can host it in a WPF application.

You can find the library at: http://gong-shell.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

You can also check this out.  It's fresh to the market and you'll need to pay, but it was designed to be identical in every way to the Windows Explorer Chrome:

http://www.teraque.com/products/explorer-chrome-suite/

The controls you get for free from WPF look like crap.  They are only meant to get developers started.